# How to Extract relational data faster than SQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-spark, etl, bigdata

I have a graph-like data in SQL. The data can be described as:

1. products table - list of skus classified into two (2)

   ```
   Class 1: non-vehicle specific (universally fits all vehicle)
   Class 2: vehicle-specific (custom-fit to specific set of vehicle) 
             1 sku fits one or more vehicle (YMMSE)
   ```
2. vehicle master table (year, make model, submodel, engine) aka YMMSE
       e.g. 
          2014 Ford Fiesta S 4 Cylinder, 1.6L
3. applications tables - relationship between custom-fit products and the corresponding vehicles YMMSE.

I have an applications table that runs into Gigabytes with approximately 85 Million records.

The problem is querying for SKU specific vehicle YMMSE takes a long time in SQL especially on skus that has a lot of applications mapping aka "almost-universal".

The applications table gets updated frequently so I need to be able to perform the expensive queries every-time until such point that the MySQL server is almost giving up or causes replication delays as a result.

The question is:

Would a distributed processing framework like Hadoop or Spark be able to help me speed up the process of discovering sku-specific vehicle mapping fast?

Regards,
Jun

Comment: Gigabytes of data over 85 million records is really not that much.  Have you defined an index on your products table in which SKU is the left-most column, and an index on your applications table in which the vehicle code is the left-most column?  By "replication delays", do you mean that you are using MySQL [Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html)—if so, then you will probably need to elucidate a little further on your exact replication setup, and exactly what are the delays to which you are referring.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding. Yes, we have the necessary indexes required but I just think that queries takes longer than I expected. With the number of  records we need to process daily, I am trying to look for solutions to make the process much faster.

Comment: If you have suitable indexing, I'd expect those queries to execute within milliseconds.  Please post the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`), the full query you are using and its execution plan (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`).

Comment: Hi @eggyal  - unfortunately the schema is proprietary. I was just exploring whether ETL-like approach would work more faster in the long run by -- exporting each participating table as data file, loading them to hadoop (or similar framework) and running map-reduce to group data that are associated in multiple pipelne in order to generate a data file where sku is the main key and values are list of vehicles.

Comment: By all means distil your problem down into a (non-proprietary) [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us.  The issue of RDBMS vs Hadoop is about far more than just performance: issues of data modelling and ACID guarantees would, generally, be of far greater concern.  In the general case, I wouldn't expect a problem to "outgrow" an RDBMS until one is talking in the *trillions* of records—which is nowhere near where you are.  If performance is your only issue, then focus on fixing that: MySQL is more than capable of delivering the speed you require.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks like Hadoop or Spark can help to remove some pressure from your database but are not designed for low-latency operations. If data is graphical and queries represent some types of graph traversal you'd be better with dedicated tools like some type of graph database.